# Loading C++ Program onto VxWorks

Tags: linux, windows, target, rtos, vxworks

I am wondering what would be needed to load a C++ or C file onto VxWorks to then be able to run the program. As of now I have a VxWorks instance running on a Linux console on a Windows machine.

I can view the directories inside of the VxWorks instance, but I am wondering how I can load files onto one of the VxWorks directories, or allow VxWorks to view the files on my Windows C: drive.

Many thanks.

Attempted to view C: drive from VxWorks instance. Was unable to view any files besides the ones stated within the RTOS.